# массив состоящий из рандомных элементов(чисел), каждый элемент это число от 0 до 8

Tags: javascript

Как сделать функцию которая возвращает массив состоящий из трех элементов, каждый элемент это рандомное число от 0 до 8 и что-бы эти три элемента(числа) не повторялись между собой.

Например:

```
let arr = [3,1,8]
let arr = [7,4,6]
let arr = [5,0,2]
```

и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Заполнить массив значениями от 0 до 8
2. Перемешать
3. Орезать первые последние 6 значений (чтобы в массиве осталось три)
4. PROFIT

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy ес)

Answer (score 1):

Вырезать из массива рандомно по одному элементу.

```js
function getA3(){
  const a = [...Array(9).keys()]
  const b = Array(3)
  let count = 3
  while(--count >= 0) { b[count] = a.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length), 1)[0]  }
  return b
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(getA3()));
console.log(JSON.stringify(getA3()));
console.log(JSON.stringify(getA3()));
```

Оставить рандомно 3 элемента

```js
function getA3(){
  const a = [...Array(9).keys()]
  let count = 6
  while(--count >= 0) { a.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length), 1) }
  return a
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(getA3()));
console.log(JSON.stringify(getA3()));
console.log(JSON.stringify(getA3()));
```

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Не все, а во втором варианте, что никак не противоречит задаче.

Answer (score 1):

Решил так:

```
function myArr(num){
   
   let newArr = Array(num).fill().map((e, i) => i + 1)

   for (let i = newArr.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      [newArr[i], newArr[j]] = [newArr[j], newArr[i]];
    }

   return newArr.splice(0, 3)
}
console.log(myArr(8));
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Какое удивительное *совпадение*, у вас со Станиславом практически идентичные ответы...

Comment: @ΝNL993, наши ответы достаточно разные. Я не перемешиваю весь массив, только три его элемента. Кроме того у нас тут образовался месячник Фишера-Йёйтса. В похожести ответов ничего удивительного.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант [Фишера-Йейтса](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%99%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%B0):

```js
const sample = (n, k) => {
    const a = [...Array(n).keys()];
    for (let i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
        const j = i + Math.floor(Math.random() * (n - i));  // random in [i, n)
        [a[i], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i]];                        // swap a[i], a[j]
    }
    return a.slice(0, k);
};

for (let k = 0; k < 10; ++k) {
    console.log(sample(9, 3).join(' '));
}
```